# How to pick up and remove %u200B from incoming links

Tags: php, unicode, pdo, utf-8

One of our partner websites is sending through a tracking field on our link and the query string looks like this:

```
?tracking=value%u200B
```

When "value" gets looked up in our DB via PHP PDO, it kills the query (fatal error). I'd have thought prepared statements would cope with this but I guess not!

How can I pick up any codes like this during the initial hit on my website to keep the strings clean?

This has to be better than simply asking them to fix the URL in case other site do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. If you know your value pattern you can do preg_replace to clean out unwanted string. If you know your messy value always starts with % and your actual value never contains % then you can do something similar to below.
You should also check with your partner website so that they will not send you anything undesired.

```
echo substr($_GET['tracking'], 0, strpos($_GET['tracking'], '%'));
```